# FontAwesome icons not showing after import

Tags: font-awesome, tailwind-css

I'm using fontawesome version 6.1.2 installed using npm, and I'm using tailwind to import it but the icon doesn't appear, when I manually import it into a css file (without building from tailwind) the icon appears successfully, how to solve it? thanks

my tailwind css file

```
@import "~/../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
@tailwind base;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind components;
```

Answer (score 0):

npm installed packages should never need to be imported with a path to your node_modules folder.  Simply import like so:

```js
@import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

Comment: thanks, but the problem is still not solved